# Table header sorting changes the position of rows

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have an html table like this below:

```
name        number       contractid

sebastian      01             aea123
sab            02             aea534
jack           03             are152
```

My problem is when I click on the name the name column is sorting in alphabetical order and the position of rows is same its fine. But when I click on the column again the rows change their position, like below. (*The first row will be moved to the empty space and second row is moved to first place.*)

```
name        number       contractid
sebastian      01             aea123
sab            02             aea534
jack           03             are152
```

Is there any solution for reducing this change in position? Any CSS and Javascript properties I can do/set for preventing this kind of jumping?

Comment: Please post the relevant code and if possible a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Were those two tables supposed to be different? Because as it stands, I'm not sure what the issue is. Also, what's the JavaScript?

Comment: i have done javascript code for table column sorting and m problem is when i click on the table header name the columns are sorting fine when i click on the table name again the position of rows changed .. as i mentioned in my second table...

Comment: Your two table demonstrations appear to be identical.

Comment: @user682417: tables 1 and 2 in your question are currently identical. Can you clarify?

Comment: ya the two tables are same..... I have defined second table for understanding my problem ....

Comment: Ok, so when I edited the space out of the first example table, that was supposed to be there?

Comment: So when you sort by the header twice in a row, it moves/removes (which one?) the empty row? Also, we really need the markup/code and preferably a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options exist, either:

1. Remove the empty row altogether and style your Html so that the space that is getting lost is created using css. This will give you more desirable formatting along with cleaner html and you won't rely on the html.
2. Insert the extra row as `th` rather than `tr` as in http://jsfiddle.net/6kczk/

I'd say option one is most sane if you can get a reasonable look, since if you have no borders all you need is some extra spacing.

Given a lack of specifics, I'm just using educated guesswork here. Whether option two would work depends on the sorting code and the assumptions made. If it assumes the first row is always the column header or gets confused when it finds extra rows of headers then it will be unlikely to work.